# CMD/BAT Взять часть строки

Tags: cmd, bat

Все действие происходит в Batch файле.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, мне нужно взять часть строки из строчной переменной или из файла. Зная номер символа начала подстроки и номер символа конца подстроки.
**Например:**
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
Допустим необходимо вытащить отсюда "stackoverflow" и я задаю номера:12(Нумерация с 1) и 24.
Возможно ли такое вообще

Comment: Надо учитывать, что в самом батнике, строчка, которую нужно найти будет рандомной, но известно ее положение и длина

Comment: Без примера не совсем понятно что это всё значит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Два варианта.

Просто указываем диапазон сразу в коде. Где первая цифра это номер символа, причем отсчет идет не с 1, а с 0. Вторая цифра длина подстроки.

```
set a=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
set b=%a:~11,13%
echo %b%
pause
```

Либо указываем в переменных 12 и 24. Вычисляем нужные цифры используя дополнительные переменные.

```
set a=https://ru.stackoverflow.com/
set start=12
set end=24
set /a n=%start%-1
echo %n%
set /a m=%end%-%n%
echo %m%
REM переменные нельзя использовать внутри переменной, но можно это сделать используя call
call set b=%%a:~%n%,%m%%%
echo %b%
pause
```

В консоли `cmd.exe` можно набрать `set /?` и посмотреть подробное описание как получать подстроки и выполнять арифметические операции.

Еще советую почитать про команду set и переменные вот здесь https://safezone.cc/threads/peremennye-v-cmd-komanda-set-i-arifmetika.22660/

Comment: Спасибо большое)